# vim: trying to work with xmledit (xml tags autocompletion)

Tags: xml, vim, autocomplete

I have installed vim and then i copied the [`xml.vim`](https://github.com/sukima/xmledit/tree/master/ftplugin) file inside `~/.vim/ftplugin.`

Then I open a `.xml` file but after writing `<foobar>` it doesn't autocomplete the closing tag..

Any idea?

Comment: open vim, type `:filetype` what is the output?

Comment: I asked you on IRC if and why you didn't follow the installation instruction. May I ask again?

Comment: @romainl i didn't understand exactly the instructions (even now i don't understand them exactly..) I thought that would be enought (like in many other cases) just copy the xml.vim to my `.vim/plugin folder` :).. The instructions mention a .vba that i can not see.. I tried `make install` and the output is `rsync -Rv ftplugin/xml.vim doc/xml-plugin.txt /home/tirengarfio/.vim/
doc/xml-plugin.txt
ftplugin/xml.vim` what should i do then? I copied the `xmledit_zip_extracted/ftplugin/xml.vim` to my `~/.vim/ftplugin` but the autocompletion doesn't work. `:scriptnames` doesn't show xml.vim.

Comment: The instructions are quite clear: you build a `xmledit.vba`, open it in vim, source it with `:so %` and you are done. Doing the steps above got me a seemingly perfectly working plugin which does everything it's supposed to do (completion on `>`, surround with tag, delete surrounding tag…) in a lot less than a minute. So 1. Install the plugin correctly, 2. read `:h xml-plugin.txt` from `gg` to `G`, 3. try it on an XML file and 4. come back here if something doesn't work or ask the author/maintaineer for help on Github.

Comment: @romainl - thanks for `:h xml-plugin.txt` - I'd been looking for the documentation